# Custom 404 page gives me a 403 error

Tags: iis-8

I have a default webpage in my IIS 8 and I want it to redirect not found URLs to an asp.net application on the same server.

So I've enabled the custom errors and changed the 404 page to "/shorturl/Redirection.aspx". But if I do that, it gives me a 403 error: "The website declined to show this webpage".

Opening the page by hand works (except that it crashes, because it needs a parameter).

Any idea why it's not working if I redirect it?

Comment: Do you get the same message if you run this on the server? And does it work in debug mode within VS?

Comment: I can't add the tilde: "The specified URL is invalid. It must be a relative URL path that begins with "/".". I get the same message on the server and I couldn't check it in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect your redirection is actually pointing to the wrong place... Try making it ~/shorturl/Redirection.aspx (note the tilde ~ ) assuming that shortcut is a folder in your root directory.

Comment: I can't add the tilde: "The specified URL is invalid. It must be a relative URL path that begins with "/".".

Comment: hmm... but you maybe somehow right. If I redirect it to /shorturl/aihwfwf.aspx it shows me the same error.

Comment: Are you doing the redirect from within a web.config page? And if so, is it a webform or MVC site?

Answer (score 0):

It was some kind of security problem. The page actually didn't redirect, but immediately showed the 403 error.